# Bound function returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to add a bound function to my Web API 2.2 OData v4 controller, but it returns 404 with the error message:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:2390/Hierarchies('300924834')/FullHierarchy'.","innererror":{
      "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

This is my method on the `HierarchiesController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult FullHierarchy([FromODataUri]string key)
{
     return Ok(new Hierarchy());
}
```

I tried to add the attribute `[ODataRoute("Hierarchies({key}/FullHierarchy)")]`on my method but then I got the following error on the line `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`when first running the application:

> The path template 'Hierarchies({key}/FullHierarchy)' on the action 'FullHierarchy' in controller 'Hierarchies' is not a valid OData path template. Bad Request - Error in query syntax.

This is my configuration in WebApiConfig:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.Namespace = ""; // tried with and without this line.

var hierachyType = builder.EntitySet<Hierarchy>("Hierarchies").EntityType;
hierachyType.Function("FullHierarchy").Returns<Hierarchy>();
```

Note that bound functions to collections don't work as well, **but unbound functions do work.**

This is how my `$metadata` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Entities.Models">
            <EntityType Name="Hierarchy">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="Policy" Type="Entities.Models.Policy" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="Nodes" Type="Collection(Entities.Models.HierarchyNode)" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Node" OpenType="true">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Site" BaseType="Entities.Models.Node" OpenType="true">
                <Property Name="Address" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Policy">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="Rules" Type="Collection(Entities.Rules.Rule)" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="HierarchyNode">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="Nodes" Type="Collection(Entities.Models.HierarchyNode)" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Building" BaseType="Entities.Models.Node" OpenType="true">
                <Property Name="StaffCount" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Source" BaseType="Entities.Models.Node" OpenType="true">
                <Property Name="GroupByOperation" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Factor" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Entities.Rules">
            <EntityType Name="Rule" Abstract="true">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="NodeType" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ParentChildRule" BaseType="Entities.Rules.Rule">
                <Property Name="AllowedParentsTypes" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ForbiddenParentsTypes" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PredicateRule_1OfTNode" BaseType="Entities.Rules.Rule">
                <Property Name="Predicate" Type="System.Linq.Expressions.Expression_1OfFunc_2OfTNode_String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PropertyRule" BaseType="Entities.Rules.Rule">
                <Property Name="RequiredProperties" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="System.Linq.Expressions">
            <ComplexType Name="Expression_1OfFunc_2OfTNode_String">
                <Property Name="Parameters" Type="Collection(System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression)" />
            </ComplexType>
            <ComplexType Name="ParameterExpression" />
        </Schema>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <Function Name="FullHierarchy" IsBound="true">
                <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Entities.Models.Hierarchy" />
                <ReturnType Type="Entities.Models.Hierarchy" />
            </Function>
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="Hierarchies" EntityType="Entities.Models.Hierarchy" />
                <EntitySet Name="Nodes" EntityType="Entities.Models.Node" />
                <EntitySet Name="Sites" EntityType="Entities.Models.Site" />
                <EntitySet Name="Rules" EntityType="Entities.Rules.Rule" />
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things:

1. The schema needs to have a namespace. I.e. `builder.Namespace = "";` needs to be removed or replaced with a non-empty string.
2. The function needs to be invoked by it's fully qualified name. I.e. The request URL needs to be `http://localhost:2390/Hierarchies('300924834')/<namespace>.FullHierarchy` in which `<namespace>` should be the default namespace or the one you specify in item #1.
3. As a function bound to a single entity, writing the controller method like this is adequate:

   `[HttpGet]
   public IHttpActionResult FullHierarchy()
   {
   return Ok(new Hierarchy());
   }`

   I don't know the exact reason. I'd guess the convention model builder helps you with such routing.

It works for me, and following are my test function details:

WebApiConfig:

```
builder.EntityType<Product>().Function("SomeFunction").Returns<string>();
```

In the ProductsController:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult SomeFunction()
    {
        return Ok("Some");
    }
```

The request:

```
GET http://localhost:54017/Products(1)/Default.SomeFunction
```

Comment: Thanks Yi, I wasn't aware that the namespace is required. Also I didn't understand what you meant in section 3. By the way, do you know why the namespace is only required for bounded functions?

Comment: @gdoron I think it's required for all kinds of functions: bound, unbound, and function import. For section 3, I'm actually saying that you don't need the "[FromODataUri] string key" as parameter of the controller method representing the function.

Comment: 1. I did manage to call the unbound function without the namespace. 2. But if it's a bound function, I have to get the key of the entity. 3. Unrelated, do you know the answer to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/odata-discussion/zGP2wDYUmaE ?

Comment: Isn't there a way to omit the namespace?
At the moment, I'm calling an action as /Operations(1)/Default.Abort, but it would be nicer to have /Operations(1)/Abort
Is there a way to do it?